# Question about an invertible matrix and elementary matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Say we have an invertible matrix $A$, so if we want to find $A^{-1}$ we can do the following process:  $(A|I)\to(A'|B_1)\to(A''|B_2)\to ... \to (I|A^{-1})$$\star$.

We also know that $A^{-1}=E_1E_2...E_n$ where $E$ represent an elementary matrix.

My question is, after doing $\star$ can we say that $A^{-1}=B_1B_2...B_n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can say that $A^{-1} = B_{n}$. Try out an example like
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cc|cc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 1
\end{array}
\right]
\longrightarrow
\left[
\begin{array}{cc|cc}
1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1
\end{array}
\right]
\longrightarrow
\left[
\begin{array}{cc|cc}
1 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Comment: I see. So the answer is no.